# How to set a custom date format in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I want to display data int the next format: `14:23 Sep 10,2012`.How can I do this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use NSDateFormatter

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm MMM dd,yyyy"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"today : %@", stringFromDate);
```

Comment: For formatting options see [NSDateFormatter Date Formatting Table](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)